# Replace with Regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to replace the part the text with the same text and some extra, example:

Initial text

```
<href="../doc/d5807346.pdf" class="document">3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE</a></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

After

```
<href="../doc/d5807346.pdf" class="document" download="3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE">3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE</a></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I'm using in Notepad++ the following Regex:

- Find: ((?<=class="document">).*?(?=<))
- Replace with:  download="\1">\1

End result is not what I'm expecting, note the > between class="document" and download :

```
<href="../doc/d5807346.pdf" class="document"> download="3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE">3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE</a></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to prevent that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(class="document")>([^<]+)`
- Replace with: `$1 download="$2">$2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(class="document")      # group 1
>                       # literally >
([^<]+)                 # group 2, 1 or more any character that is not "<"
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1 + a space
download="      # literally
$2              # content of group 2
">              # literally
$2              # content f group 2
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Find: (?:class="document">)([^<]*)
2. Replace (corrected): class="document">download="$1">$1

Tested in N++

Before: `<href="../doc/d5807346.pdf" class="document">3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE</a></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>`

After: `<href="../doc/d5807346.pdf" class="document">download="3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE">3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE</a></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>`

It's helpful to Use "online Regex tester" for visual debug regular expression

Comment: This removes `class="document"` and the text `3.2.1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXAMPLE`. Have you tried it?