# Delete short lines in Notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++

How can I delete short two-character lines in a text file using Notepad++

This is an original test file:

```
U70779 Especial
P160993 Especial
DV
P091262
HX
HkP095379 E
Ty
TP
P204406
Da
AC
Arturo Cobo Lopez
B022725 Regular
MM
```

This is the expected file:

```
U70779 Especial
P160993 Especial
P091262
HkP095379 E
P204406
Arturo Cobo Lopez
B022725 Regular
```

Comment: Notepad++ [appears to support regex-based find/replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936389/replace-with-regex-in-notepad), which should make this fairly trivial. (Or the backspace key...)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what research you've done into the matter and any attempts you've made based on that research. Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a "code for karma" site, but rather a site where specific questions encountered during software programming are answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^\w{2}$\R?
Replace: (empty)
```

Here is a running [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jgla23/1).